# How to pass username and ssh password in ansible-playbook command line - Bamboo

Tags: ansible, bamboo

I have a ansible playbook which I run manually from the command line by `ansible-playbook -u <username> -k playbooks/example.yml`

The above works fine. It prompts me for a SSH password and runs the playbook.

`The ansible version in my linux machine: 2.7.7`

I need to run this in Bamboo as part of my build plan. In Bamboo, I cannot type in the password as it will not prompt me. So I want to pass the username and ssh password as part of the command as arguments.

I tried this

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/monitor-linux-node.yml -e "ansible_user=<username> ansible_ssh_pass=password"
```

This throws this error

```
ERROR: blockinfile is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
```

I also tried this

```
ansible-playbook -u <username> playbooks/monitor-linux-node.yml -e "ansible_ssh_pass=password"
```

This throws the `Usage: ansible-playbook playbook.yml` and lists the arguments we can use.

Any suggestions on how to pass the username and ssh password in the command line will be really helpful.

`The ansible version in Bamboo machine: 1.9.4`

Comment: why don't you use ssh keys?

Comment: hi @TomášPospíšek, thanks for your reply. Can you point me with a link or something?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=using+ssh+keys . Does this help you?

Comment: Very funny! *Claps*. I thought it was an ansible task which I couldn't find in the doco.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're being ironic. But my suggestion remains the same: use ssh keys instead of a password. That should help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`sshpass`](https://www.tecmint.com/sshpass-non-interactive-ssh-login-shell-script-ssh-password/)

```
sshpass -p <ssh-password> ansible-playbook -u <username> --ask-pass playbooks/monitor-linux-node.yml
```

Will be closest to what you want. If possible consider using password file

```
sshpass -f <password-file> ansible-playbook -u <username> --ask-pass playbooks/monitor-linux-node.yml
```

Note `--ask-pass` key. `sshpass` will provide password non-interactively instead of user.

If you are fine with having password stored unencrypted in a file anyway, consider using `group_vars/<group name>.yml` for defining `ansible_ssh_pass` variable. You will still need `sshpass`, but ansible will use it behind the scene.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ivan_onys. I did however use another way to bypass this, I don't remember how though. I'll have a look and post it.